# Drop columns from a DataFrame based on their data types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I drop columns from a `DataFrame` **elegantly** where the criteria is to drop all columns of a specific data type.

I have used two approaches

```
for i in df.columns:
    if(df[i].dtype)!='int64':
        df.drop(columns=i, inplace=True)
```

**Problem** - It is not the greatest of approaches plus it does not display or show data until or unless done with `inplace=True` , which is not a good thinking at all

```
df.select_dtypes(include='int64').head()
```

Second approach is to use this but it does not drop columns.

Any suggestions on a third approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exclude` parameter in [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1.3,3,5,7,1,0],

})

print (df.dtypes)
A     object
B      int64
C      int64
D    float64
dtype: object

print (df.select_dtypes(exclude='int64'))
   A    D
0  a  1.3
1  b  3.0
2  c  5.0
3  d  7.0
4  e  1.0
5  f  0.0
```

Comment: what about ```object``` ?

Comment: @Deshwal - `df.select_dtypes(exclude=object)` ?

Comment: so rther than using 2 excludes, isnt it better to use only ```include```?

Comment: @Deshwal - Yes, it depends what need - If need filter only some types use `include`, for remove use `exclude`